# How to get the Name value using Post method in php

Tags: php, post

How to get the Name value using Post method in php like this

```
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $result['name'];?>" id="">
```

How to Post the Name value..?

```
<?php

$name=$_POST[''] --? here how can i get the value using name.
```

Please help me.Thanks

Is this Correct..?
    $name=$_POST['$result['name']'];

Comment: Do you have `$result['name'];` available even after the POST?

Comment: Why do you want to generate the field name dynamically?  Usually you should have a fixed name so you can reach it easily in your script.

Comment: Loop over `$_POST` and pick whichever value you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $_POST['name'];?>" id="">
```

Comment: i given like that. But how can i get the value in the Post method for submitting data..$_POST['']..?

Comment: try to get all post variables with var_dump($_POST); or var_dump($_REQUEST);

Answer (score 0):

this is the wrong way to generate **name** dynamically... but if you really want this way only then you can do it this way..

```
<input type="hidden" value=<?php echo $result['name'];?> name="abc"/>
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $result['name'];?>" id="">
```

don't forgot to check variable is set or not using **isset()**

in php

```
if(isset($_POST['abc']))
{
    $abc=$_POST['abc'];
    $original = $_POST[$abc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use form tag to post the values from form.**

```
<form action=".." method="post">
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $result['name'];?>" id="name" name="name"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

**In php to receive the value from form.**

```
$n=$_POST['name'];
```

Comment: how can you give two name attribute?